# Call function outside of angular directive component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

Is there a way to call a function in my directive, but outside of component?

Example:

```
<ion-input #bar barcodeScanner></ion-input>
<button (click)="bar.start()" type="button">
   <i class="my-icons-scaner"></i>
</button>
```

Directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[barcodeScanner]'
})
export class BarcodeScannerDirective implements OnInit {

constructor(private _element: ElementRef) {}

 ngOnInit() {
    const element = this._element.nativeElement
    console.log({ element })
 }

 public start(){
    console.log('start?')
 }

}
```

Comment: So you want your parent component button click to call the sibling element's directive's start function?

Comment: @AustinTFrench exactly

Comment: @AustinTFrench or a clean way to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use exportAs property on the Directive decorator like this

> Defines the name that can be used in the template to assign this
> directive to a variable.

**directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[barcodeScanner]',
  exportAs: 'barcodeScanner'
})
```

Then we can access our barcodeScanner instance anywhere in our template:

```
<ion-input #bar="barcodeScanner" barcodeScanner></ion-input>
<button (click)="bar.start()" type="button">
   <i class="my-icons-scaner"></i>
</button>
```